# Deleted answer from review queue gets undeleted when question is undeleted

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-answers, link-only-answers, undeleted-questions

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23730890/revisions) was deleted from the review queue as a link-only answer.

After the answer got deleted, the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23730858/revisions) it answered was also deleted, and then undeleted. After the question was undeleted, the answer also got undeleted, whithout any trace in the revision history.

I think this is a bug. Deleted answers (from the review queue or otherwise) should not be undeleted 
with the question.

Comment: That's not necessarily true.  Were the question to be permitted, that answer is one of the more helpful that could be made - it's not a random link, but to the official documentation.  It might be better posted as a comment, but the person who provided it may not have been able to do that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am not arguing for or against the specific answer. I am just saying that *if* it is deleted from the review queue, then a delete and undelete on the question should not undelete the answer.

Comment: I hear what you are saying, but if the question is re-permitted, then its better that it's debatable quality but well intentioned answers be given a new look, too.  Otherwise we end up with a question with no answers... and that's not helpful.

Comment: @ChrisStratton And how would the system know if an answer is "well intentioned"?

Comment: I wonder if this happens as well when the answer was deleted by the poster (rather than from the review queue).

Comment: If the answer was deleted for moderation, maybe just push it (back) into the proper review queue, maybe with one auto-undelete vote? (maybe depending on the reason for deletion though)

Comment: This is a well-known bug, has been around forever.  I'm guessing they consider it too much of a corner-case to justify the cost of the dbase table design to keep track of the "formerly deleted" status.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, well intentioned answeres should not stay deleted. I was referring to answers that were deleted before the question got deleted.

Comment: But that answer was well-intentioned - perhaps the most appropriate response to that question.  It was deleted because it was marginally (non)compliant with the rules under which the question itself then got deleted - if one is allowed, then it only makes sense that they both should be.  Really, we shouldn't be deleting answers like this in the first place.

Comment: I can't imagine it's that difficult @hans. Rather than setting the deleted_date column in the posts table to null for every answer only do it when the date is greater or equal to the question deleted date. It's definitely a corner case but if so obtaining the question deleted date, if it's not known at the time, won't pose much of a burden on the DB.

Comment: @Lamak "And how would the system know if an answer is "well intentioned"?" [Nine](http://search.dilbert.com/comic/Random%20Number%20Generator) is the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for your post! I have checked in code to fix this issue and it should be working correctly once the next build goes out (> `rev 2014.6.27.2348`). If an answer is deleted before a question is, undeleting the question will no longer undelete the answer.